# How to extrude plane and subdivide at once

Tags: subdivision-surface, extrude

Halo.. im new in blender.. and i found sclupting tutorial video,there he made a plane, mirror it, scale, rotate. But then he made an object from a plane very quickly, and i don't get it how he do that. He extrude the plane and subdivide it at once can you explain please?..[image: an objeck he made from plan]

Comment: Could you add a link to the video?

Comment: Maybe he has created a shortcut, in 2.7 press W then go over Subdivide and right click to give it a shortcut